# window.opener does not work in Excel for Windows

Tags: ms-office, office-js, window.opener, shared-worker, message-channel

I have built an Excel add-in, it opens a popup by `window.open`, then the add-in communicates with the popup site. I just realised that it does NOT work in Excel for Windows, the reason is that the popup can NOT get the host by `$window.opener`.

To illustrate this and avoid cross-domain, I have made [a xml](https://www.matrixlead.com/testWindowOpener/manifest-windowopener.xml), which refers to [the add-in](https://www.matrixlead.com/testWindowOpener/Home.html) and [the test page](https://www.matrixlead.com/testWindowOpener/Window.html). It works well in Excel Online in Chrome and in IE. However, while running it in Excel for Windows, `$window.opener` returns `undefined`.

Could anyone tell me what happened, and what's the workaround?

(for people who recommend Dialog API, please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541675/storageevent-or-efficient-way-to-check-regularly-a-value-in-storage). So now neither Dialog nor `window.open` works in Excel for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

`UI.messageParent` also won't work? It's from the [official docs](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.messageparent).

Example:

```
Office.context.ui.messageParent("Message from Dialog box")
```

Docs:

> Delivers a message from the dialog box to its parent/opener page. The page calling this API must be on the same domain as the parent.

(I assume this isn't the Dialog API which you referring)

Comment: My tests show that `messageParent` works with Dialog, but my question is about using `window.open` rather than Dialog.