# Are Shared WebWorkers supported in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, web-worker, shared-worker

I tried to implement [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36146764/702977), here is [the link](http://www.matrixlead.com/testWorker/fileA.html). It works in Chrome, whereas in IE 11 it gives an error `'SharedWorker' is undefined`. But according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers), WebWorkers are supported in IE 11.

Does anyone know who is right?

Comment: Here is the right one according to your code: http://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedworkers

Comment: Web Workers are intialized with `new Worker(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web workers are indeed supported in IE 11, but shared workers not. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers):

[image]

Comment: I see... Do you think we could achieve the same task as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36146764/702977) by `Web Workers` rather than `Shared Web Workers`?

Comment: What's the goal? Bit unclear from the linked question IMO

Comment: Why not using Cross-document messaging API? http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging

Comment: Because it does not work in Excel add-in for Windows: [window.opener returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655202/window-opener-does-not-work-in-excel-for-windows).

Comment: And a Shared Worker would work from the Excel Add-in?

Comment: As Shared Worker does not work with IE, it is certain that messaging between Excel add-in and IE will not work.